# ImportError: No Module Named bs4 (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm working in Python and using Flask. When I run my main Python file on my computer, it works perfectly, but when I activate venv and run the Flask Python file in the terminal, it says that my main Python file has "No Module Named bs4." Any comments or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: pip3 install BeautifulSoup4

Comment: Lol, my problem was pipenv installing bs4 with ipython as dev packages and then later reinstalling without including dev. Moving it to prod packages worked.

Answer (score 296, accepted):

Activate the virtualenv, and then install BeautifulSoup4:

```
$ pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

When you installed `bs4` with `easy_install`, you installed it system-wide. So your system python can import it, but not your virtualenv python.
If you do not need `bs4` to be installed in your system python path, uninstall it and keep it in your virtualenv.

For more information about virtualenvs, read [this](http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/)

Comment: Imagine (for the example sake) that you're working on a project that requires a specific version of a module. You might also be working on a different project, requiring a **different** version of this module.

If each project is located in virtualenvs, you will have two absolutely independent python environments, instead of having a system python environment with two versions of the same module.

Keep your system env clean. Work in virtualenvs.

Comment: I cannot install, get error `locale.Error: unsupported locale setting` Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I can't truly guess without a traceback, but have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting

Comment: Also remember that if you're using a venv, you have to use the python binary _from that venv_. `/usr/bin/python` (on a Mac OS) is wrong; it should be `<your path to your venv>/bin/python`

Comment: I had to exit() Python so that the PIP install would work :)

Answer (score 65):

For **python2.x**:

```
sudo pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

For **python3**:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-bs4
```

Comment: The official site `crummy.com` failed to provide `python3-bs4` package name.

Comment: for python 3 too `sudo pip install BeautifulSoup4` works

Answer (score 19):

Just tagging onto Balthazar's answer. Running

```
pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

did not work for me. Instead use

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install bs4
```

Comment: This worked for me. Even ChatGPT couldn't remind me to use -m

Answer (score 13):

I have been searching far and wide in the internet.

I'm using Python 3.6 and MacOS. I have uninstalled and installed with `pip3 install bs4` but that didn't work. It seems like python is not able to detect or search the `bs4` module.

This is what worked:
`python3 -m pip install bs4`

The `-m` option allows you to add a module name.

https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html

Comment: you, my friend are a lifesaver

Comment: This works for me running Python 3.6 on iMac in the year 2022.

Answer (score 11):

```
pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
```

Try this. It works for me. The reason is well explained [here](https://python-forum.io/Thread-What-s-the-difference-between-pip-and-pip3)..

Answer (score 7):

It is so annoying to find the answer has nothing to do with BeautifulSoup. To the linux users, be vary of running the command 'python', version 2 exits and you may have forgotten to change the bash file alias of python. And so you might have created the virtual environment using 3 with

```
python3 -m venv .venv
```

So, to install things, go with

```
python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

not

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Things get installed in different versions and you scratch your head as to what is going on.

Answer (score 6):

If you use **Pycharm**, go to `preferences - project interpreter - install bs4`.

If you try to install **BeautifulSoup**, it will still show that no module named `bs4`.

Answer (score 5):

I will advise you to uninstall the bs4 library by using this command:

> pip uninstall bs4

and then install it using this command:

> sudo apt-get install python3-bs4

I was facing the same problem in my Linux Ubuntu when I used the following command for installing bs4 library:

> pip install bs4

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Anaconda for package management, following should do:

`conda install -c anaconda beautifulsoup4`

Comment: The option "-c anaconda" is the default, so "conda install beautifulsoup4" does the same and is easier to memorize :-)

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

`pipenv pip install BeautifulSoup4`

Answer (score 3):

I did what @rayid-ali said, except I'm on a Windows 10 machine so I left out the sudo. That is, I did the following:

```
python3 -m pip install bs4
```

and it worked like a pycharm. Worked like a charm anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
pip3.7 install bs4
```

Try this. It works with python 3.7

Answer (score 2):

`pip install --user BeautifulSoup4`

Answer (score 1):

A lot of tutorials/references were written for Python 2 and tell you to use pip install somename. If you're using Python 3 you want to change that to pip3 install somename.

Answer (score 1):

The better method is ("-U" : Upgrade all package(s) to the  newest  available  version.) :

```
$ python3 -m pip install -U pip && python3 -m pip install -U bs4
```

or install from apt (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, etc.) :

```
$ sudo apt install python3-bs4
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is using easy_install.

```
easy_install bs4
```

It will work if pip fails.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try install bs4 with

```
pip install --ignore-installed BeautifulSoup4
```

if the methods above didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the module
OR
Try installing with beautiful soup with the below command

```
pip install --ignore-installed BeautifulSoup4
```

Answer (score 0):

Addendum to the original query:
modules.py

```
help('modules')

$python modules.py
```

It lists that module bs4 already been installed.

```
_codecs_kr          blinker             json                six
_codecs_tw          brotli              kaitaistruct        smtpd
_collections        bs4                 keyword             smtplib
_collections_abc    builtins            ldap3               sndhdr
_compat_pickle      bz2                 lib2to3             socket
```

Proper solution is:

```
pip install --upgrade bs4
```

Should solve the problem.

Not only that, it will show same error for other modules as well.
So you got to issue the pip command same way as above for those errored module(s).

Answer (score 0):

In case you are behind corporate proxy then try using following command

pip install --proxy=http://www-YOUR_PROXY_URL.com:PROXY_PORT BeautifulSoup4

Answer (score 0):

One more solution for `PyCharm`:

Go to `File -> Settings -> Python Interpreter`, click on `plus` sign and find `beautifulsoup4`.

Click `install`.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this problem with `Python 3`. In my case I was able to solve it by running:

```
$ pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
```

Instead of:

```
$ pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have pip in your PATH environment variable. If you don't have it then use this link: `python -m pip install beautifulsoup4`

This worked for me. Hopefully, it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the when do

```py
pip install beautifullsoap4
```

always gets installed to my python3.9 package
where my

```
python3 --version
```

gave the output as `Python 3.10.6`
I fixed the issue of pip3 install by upgrading the pip and pointing correctly to `3.10` instead of `3.9`

Then everything worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

After reading all the answers, what worked for me was adding the `--clean` option with `pyinstaller`.

Example:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --console --clean --name Email_Parser main.py
```

What I tried and did not work:

1. Deleting and recreating the virtual environment
2. `python -m pyinstaller`
3. Installing pyinstaller in the virtual environment