# ImportError: No module named bs4 in Windows

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup, captcha

I am trying to create a script to download the captcha from my website.
I think the code works except from that error, when I run it in cmd (I am using windows not Linux) I receive the following:

```sh
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

I tried using `pip install BeautifulSoup4`
but then I receive a syntax error at install.

Here is the script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import urllib

url = "https://example.com"
content = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
img = soup.find('img',id ='imgCaptcha')
print img
urllib.urlretrieve(urlparse.urljoin(url, img['src']), 'captcha.bmp')
```

The problem according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11784778/3065448) must be due to the fact I have not activated the virtualenv, and THEN install BeautifulSoup4.

I don't think this information will be of any help but I saved my python text in a notepad.py and the run it using cmd.

Comment: Where are you running the command `pip install BeautifulSoup4`? The fact that you are getting a syntax error suggests to me that you might be running the command in the Python shell, which is incorrect - you need to run it in the windows command line.

Comment: I ran the above code in windows command line, which did not work and showed the above error and the afterwards I added `pip install BeautifulSoup4` on top of `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` and then a syntax error appeared.

Comment: I agree but I do not know how to solve the installation errors

Comment: The command `pip install BeautifulSoup4` must not be part of your Python code. Open the Windows command line and type `pip install BeautifulSoup4`. Then try running your code.

Comment: I just tried that and it says `pip is not regognized`.. I guess I must install something from here: [pip python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)

Comment: Correct - install `pip`, then follow my instructions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem until a moment ago. Thanks for the post and comments! According to @Martin Vseticka 's suggestion I checked if I have the pip.exe file in my python folders. I run python 2.7 and 3.7 simultaneously. I didn't have it in the python 2.7 folder but in the 3.7. 
So in the command line I changed the directory to where the pip.exe file was located. Then I ran "pip install BeautifulSoup4" and it worked. See enclosed screen shot. [image]

Comment: in Windows, you can use the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?highlight=python%20launcher#python-launcher-for-windows) to ensure you are running python from the correct install (i.e. 2.7, 3.6, 3.7, etc.). You can either do this with each run (`py -3.7 -m pip`) or setup a default version to run (i.e. `PYTHON_PY 3.7` environment variable, then just use `py -m pip`).

Comment: Thanks for sharing @LightCC - the post is 6 years old. I am sure there have been plenty of up-dates in the mean time. In general I found the Anaconda environment quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

I did a fresh install of Python 3.5 on my Windows 8.1 (64b) machine and then run:

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts>pip install b
eautifulsoup4
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (81kB)
    100% |################################| 81kB 890kB/s
Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4
Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.4.1
```

and then run:

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>python test.py
```

`test.py` contains only:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I received no error.

Comment: I see no `pip install beautifulsoup4` in my scripts folder, can you please tell me where you downloaded?, sorry for being handful

Comment: I have `pip.exe` file in `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts` folder. I did standard installation of Python 3.5. No additional installing is needed.

Comment: You should see pip.exe in the `Scripts` folder (I used `pip` to run `pip.exe` for short).

Comment: I guess something is messed up here so i'll try reinstalling it, I'll be back

Answer (score 0):

I have python3.7 32bit and python3.7 64 bit installed on Windows 10.
For this app, I am using the 32 bit version.
I was getting the following error:

```sh
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

when I was trying to 'import bs4' from my app.py. Someone said: "Make sure your pip and your python are both 32 bits", but omitted to explicitly say how, so here it is:

1. Delete your virtual environment if it exists.
2. Create a new venv using `python -m venv venv`, but explicitly call it from your 32bit python directory like this:
   C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python -m venv my_venv
3. install the requirements by explicitly calling the 32bit version like this:

```sh
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip install -r requirements.txt
```

That's it. I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I could install bs4, but still got an error message like yours. My operation system is 64 bit, and I only had this issue after I installed the latest Python in "32 bit" version. So I removed the 32 bit one, then I can import the bs4 again, and it still works after I install the latest Python in 64 version. Hope it helps.