# ImportError: No module named 'bs4' with virtualenv python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I know this is a common issue but I still can't figure how to make it work.
I'm trying to use bs4 inside a virtual environment but I have this error `ImportError: No module named 'bs4'`

I have my virtualenv activated :

```
pip install bs4
Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in /home/****/.virtualenvs/****/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /home/****/.virtualenvs/****/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from bs4)
```

My scripts start with

```
!/usr/bin/python3.5 
# -*-coding:Utf-8 -*
import json
import hashlib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Any help is welcome !

Comment: Are you running the script in virtual env. Maybe you forgot to activate it

Comment: `pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4` already tried?

Comment: Are you sure you did pip install bs4 in your virtual env?

Comment: You need to activate the virtualenv before running the script

Comment: Can you check that your script is using the right version of python (with: import sys, print(sys.version)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No Module Named bs4 (BeautifulSoup)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783875/importerror-no-module-named-bs4-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the right python?  If you have everything tied up in a virtual environment, then you need to be using python from inside that virtualenv.  The command:

```
which python
```

at a bash prompt should tell you what the command:

```
python
```

points to.
From the look of your script, you are asking it to go to /usr/bin/python3.5, which is not the directory of your virtualenv, by looking at your path, it is somewhere in your home directory.  Try changing the path in your script to the python virtualenv version (the one which pip has found bs4 in).