# Beautiful soup cant be found after multiple reinstalls

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm not sure what's going on but no matter what I've tried, when I go to `import bs4` the module is not found. I'm at a loss as to how I can get it to find the package.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tonywinglau/Desktop/print('hello LeChristopher').py", line 1, in <module>
    import bs4 as bs
ImportError: No module named bs4
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/usr/bin/python2.7', "/Users/tonywinglau/Desktop/print('helloLeChristopher').py"]]
[dir:/Users/tonywinglau/Desktop]
[path:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin]
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783875/importerror-no-module-named-bs4-beautifulsoup).

Comment: can u try  import BeautifulSoup

Comment: No just `import BeautifulSoup` doesnt work

Comment: check link which is provided by @not_a_robot, answer is given

Comment: run pip freeze and check if it is in the list. If you are not using virtualenv, i recommend you do it.

Comment: Or try `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`...

Comment: @not_a_robot again, no luck

Comment: @cdvv7788 good call, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

In my global environment I cant say the issue was figured out but installing virtualenv worked.
After creating a virutal environment via `virtualenv myproject && pip install BeautifulSoup`

---

`import BeautifulSoup` - runs without error.