# How can I install BeautifulSoup? I keep getting "No module named bs4"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I try to

```
import bs4
```

I keep getting the error

```
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

I have tried to address this by trying all of the following (individually and together) with Python 2 and Python 3 and have had no success. What's going wrong?

```
sudo pip2 install beautifulsoup4
sudo pip3 install beautifulsoup4

sudo apt-get install python-bs4
sudo apt-get install python3-bs4
```

Comment: What happens when you run those last four commands? What error messages do you get?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11783875/560648 ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I see no error messages when I run those install commands. All seems to install properly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for the link. I have already tried the solutions presented in that question.

Comment: Show us what you see, exactly. We cannot guess.

Answer (score 0):

Downoad it from [Pypi beatifulsoup4](https://pypi.python.org/packages/fa/8d/1d14391fdaed5abada4e0f63543fef49b8331a34ca60c88bd521bcf7f782/beautifulsoup4-4.6.0.tar.gz#md5=c17714d0f91a23b708a592cb3c697728)

and find setup.py file after extracting, then install it with

```
sudo python setup.py install
```