# Installing package via pip works fine but still import error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using this python version

```
 Python 3.7.0
```

And this pip version

```
 pip 18.0
```

And then I install the bs4 package

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
pip install bs4
```

This all works (without errors) but now when I run a python script with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No Module Named bs4 (BeautifulSoup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783875/importerror-no-module-named-bs4-beautifulsoup)

Comment: I tried and works fine. Are you in a different virtualenv? Can you explain how and where you install and you run python? Seems like you are installing the library in a different virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are trying to install BeautifulSoup4. If so, try:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

and then you will be able to import bs4 using:

`import bs4`

Comment: I tried this but im running into another error know... See above for me edited question. Any thoughts?