# trying to use urllib.request from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x

I'm on chapter 20 on The self taught Programmer: and I got an error using the import urllib.request from bs4 import beautifulsoup

import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Scraper:
    def **init**(self, site):
        self.site = site

```
def scrape(self):
    r = urllib.request\
        .urlopen(self.site)
    html = r.read()
    parser = "html.parser"
    sp = BeautifulSoup(html,
                       parser)
    for tag in sp.find_all("a"):
        url = tag.get("href")
        if url is None:
            continue
        if "html" in url:
            print("\n" + url)
```

news = "https://news.google.com/"
Scraper(news).scrape()

error below
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yunge/OneDrive/Desktop/SelftaughtPra/google_news.py", line 2, in 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

> > >

Comment: Take a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783875/importerror-no-module-named-bs4-beautifulsoup).

Comment: I tried all of the code it did't work for me. I using window too.

Comment: You were not supposed to try the code. You were supposed to install bs4 by running `pip install beautifulsoup4` in a Command Prompt.

Comment: I tried that code it says its already installed.